# Convert Quotes Using htmlspecialchars AND Keep HTML Tags in PHP

Tags: php, html, quotes, double-quotes, htmlspecialchars

I have a hidden input tag that I want its value to have quotes in it. How would I escape the quotes so that I can use it for the value?

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="edited_terms" 
value="<p>\"Please enter any additional terms and conditions here.\"</p>" />
```

PHP

```
$terms = mysql_real_escape_string($terms);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="edited_terms" value="'.$terms.'" />';
```

I would like to use both single and double quotes, however setting it to `value='<p>\"Please enter any additional terms and conditions here.\"</p>'` won't let me use single quotes.

The function `htmlspecialchars` let's me accomplish this but it will get rid of HTML tags. For example, `<p>` will be converted to `&lt;p&gt;`. I want to be able to keep the `<p>` tags and convert the quotes to `&quot;`.

Comment: your question is not clear, why you need this? also why you escaped the double quota when you used single quota in the last example? `value='<p>\"Pleas...`

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() is like the last function you will ever have to use in cakephp or any better php code for that matter.

Comment: @Akam I need this for a website that I'm making. I escaped the double quotes because to show the error that I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Daniel:

```
<input name="edited_terms" 
value="<p>&quot;Please enter any additional terms and conditions here.&quot;</p>" />
```

**Update PHP:**

```
$terms ="<p>&quot;Please enter any additional terms and conditions here.&quot;</p>";           
echo '<input type="hidden" name="edited_terms" value="'.$terms.'" />';
```

Comment: How would I do this in PHP?

Comment: @Daniel click here to see a result [phpsandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42e3b8a3ed4ed815bde18b65d3504bcda60c9a7b)

Answer (score 0):

First, HTML is not MySQL. So MySQL functions won’t help here.

Second, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on the HTML attribute value:

```
$terms = htmlspecialchars($terms);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="edited_terms" value="'.$terms.'" />';
```

For attribute values in single quotes, use `htmlspecialchars` with *ENT_QUOTES* flag.

Comment: If I use `htmlspecialchars`, it will transform `<p>` tags into `&lt;p&gt;` which I don't want. How would I use it without doing this.

Comment: @Daniel The resulting value is the same.